# How do I get my button to redirect to a web page within the app?

Tags: codenameone

So far, I have it so that when a user presses a button, a browser opens and redirects the user to my desired url. However, I want this to happen within the app instead of a web tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Define a xml layout containing a widget called webview. Then in your activity you implement a listener to your button which invokes that xml with the desired page to load inside your webview. Google to find some code and return here with your code problems, if you find some. If this will be the case, open new questions provinding detailed info about your matters then we can help more. Best.

EDIT: Excuse me, just now, re-reading your question I think I really understand it, and the solution is very simple, just a line of code (to instruct your app to open a webpage inside your webview, and not the regular browser, outside your app). Try this:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // needed to open url inside our webview, otherwise it will open at the default browser
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Excuse me, only now I see what you need. Edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Had luck with that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BrowserComponent`, just add it to the center of a border layout form and set the URL for that component. Check out the list of main components in Codename One within the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html).